# How to enable Security logging in WCF Service using auditLogLocation="Security"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, wcf-security

I am working on WCF Logging module. I want to enable all Security logging with WCF Service. like there are three options in `auditLogLocation="Application | Security | Default`. I have used `Application` but I want to enable `Security` option. I read this link [Auditing Security Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731669%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

All I want to know how to enable `SeAuditPrivilege` and `SeSecurityPrivilege` in WCF Service.

> Here is my configuration

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" suppressAuditFailure="true" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure"
            messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure WCF Security Auditing, to log security events to the Windows event log, by specifying the following in the configuration file:

Service Behavior definition: (e.g.)

```
<behaviors>
   <behavior name="myAuditBehavior">
      <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application"
            suppressAuditFailure="false" 
            serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="None" 
            messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
      </behavior>
</behaviors>
```

Service Behavior referenced in the service definition:

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration=" myAuditBehavior" ...
       <endpoint
```

Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734737(v=vs.110).aspx

Note: you do not show the service section of your configuration section, so you need to make sure the service is using correct behavior.

Regards,

Comment: do we need to change `auditLogLocation="Application"` to `Security` ?

Comment: I think you can decide where you want the events written, either the Application or Security event log.  The following snippet explains:  The AuditLogLocation enumeration has three values: Application, Security, or Default. The value specifies one of the logs visible in the Event Viewer, either the Security log or the Application log.

Comment: When i use above Configuration with some changes like `Contract` its stops working

Comment: You may want to check the WCF trace file to see why it "stops working".  Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx